# Application error when deploying the application in Heroku

Tags: java, android, heroku, backend, ktor

[image]

Check the logs and see smth like this:

```
heroku logs --tail
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633380+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:338)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633430+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633479+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:143)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633522+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:277)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633582+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633639+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.ServerKt.main(Server.kt:7)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633772+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633828+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1022)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633878+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.storage.exposed.LocalSourceImpl.<init>(LocalSourceImpl.kt:40)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633922+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.di.KoinModuleKt$getKoinModule$1$1.invoke(KoinModule.kt:9)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.633963+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.di.KoinModuleKt$getKoinModule$1$1.invoke(KoinModule.kt:9)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.634006+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
2022-08-12T09:25:27.634058+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 43 more
2022-08-12T09:25:27.775983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-12T09:25:27.838422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T09:25:27.842121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-12T09:25:30.809372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar backend/build/libs/Backend.jar  $JAR_OPTS`
2022-08-12T09:25:31.577929+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-08-12T09:25:31.582796+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2022-08-12T09:25:31.843279+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2022-08-12T09:25:33.015253+00:00 app[web.1]: 09:25:33.013 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
2022-08-12T09:25:33.021713+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Singleton:'com.mandarine.backend.storage.exposed.LocalSource']
2022-08-12T09:25:33.021832+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:60)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.021920+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:46)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.021921+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:53)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.021962+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory$get$1.invoke(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022000+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.mp.KoinPlatformTools.synchronized(PlatformToolsJVM.kt:20)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022036+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:51)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022074+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:103)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022113+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:223)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022158+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:211)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022196+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:193)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022233+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.MainKt$module$$inlined$inject$default$1.invoke(KtorApplicationExt.kt:79)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022270+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022305+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.MainKt.module$lambda-0(Main.kt:19)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022341+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.MainKt.access$module$lambda-0(Main.kt:1)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022377+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.MainKt$module$2.invoke(Main.kt:22)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022414+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.MainKt$module$2.invoke(Main.kt:21)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022457+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature.install(Routing.kt:106)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022517+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature.install(Routing.kt:88)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022562+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.application.ApplicationFeatureKt.install(ApplicationFeature.kt:68)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022594+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.MainKt.module(Main.kt:21)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022627+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022660+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022696+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022728+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022761+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022793+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022826+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022858+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:159)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022891+00:00 app[web.1]: at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022924+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022956+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.022992+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:332)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023027+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023062+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:356)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023095+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023127+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:30)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023172+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:312)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023206+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023266+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:338)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023318+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023354+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:143)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023386+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:277)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023419+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023469+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.ServerKt.main(Server.kt:7)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023549+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023582+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1022)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023623+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.storage.exposed.LocalSourceImpl.<init>(LocalSourceImpl.kt:40)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023667+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.di.KoinModuleKt$getKoinModule$1$1.invoke(KoinModule.kt:9)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023697+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.mandarine.backend.di.KoinModuleKt$getKoinModule$1$1.invoke(KoinModule.kt:9)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023727+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:53)
2022-08-12T09:25:33.023761+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 43 more
2022-08-12T09:25:33.168870+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-12T09:25:33.231717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T09:26:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:27:09.997129+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 50374f6b by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:27:09.997129+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:27:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-12T09:27:10.151063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2022-08-12T09:28:37.643765+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=3c8745a0-bb7f-44e0-9da0-c655660ead4d fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:28:38.048345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=eaf2c3c0-4272-438d-aaa3-47fe55b5d133 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:28:43.014626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/pet" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=e874bc27-436f-4fc1-b741-8e3a6aa02901 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:28:43.177506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=e5bdc5f1-6fd2-40e0-83ee-850bc60360aa fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:29:04.800358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=0d40b79f-873d-4f0d-a0f4-4c373f913e84 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:29:04.984968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=ec2d2723-6829-4aa9-9c1e-f9e9f9acdb92 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:29:58.364829+00:00 app[api]: Running release v5 commands by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:29:58.364829+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-rectangular-09986) by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:29:58.377717+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-rectangular-09986 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:29:58.377717+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user morozovvadim91@gmail.com
2022-08-12T09:30:13.471875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=99eb931a-93e3-4afd-8ce1-bcd339f01c35 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:30:13.642908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=730c1e88-a43e-430e-adc9-29a6efe17d82 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:34:36.404222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=e5ff29f2-e697-4c34-ac0f-5cd42ee85f06 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:34:36.742105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=a9ec8fa9-8322-405e-b302-873a3e9cba5a fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:38:07.072408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/pets" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=655ef66f-c515-47a5-b673-6679eae370c1 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:38:07.231727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=c81c85e0-7505-497a-836f-5a48582e2249 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:38:12.543740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/pet" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=2d232db2-903d-4030-abea-c1c790e0b68e fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:38:12.714060+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=9db26ddb-dd49-4d2f-a5c8-39818e2c1f4f fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:39:47.629100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/pet" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=b4f4c4c6-8aa2-46db-b7d6-7702dab1d2bc fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T09:39:47.780409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-temple-20840.herokuapp.com request_id=17046ade-434f-4b79-b42d-ed4c501e5722 fwd="195.22.227.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Probably you need to configure a config var for the `jdbcUrl` to make it accessible as an environment variable in your application https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#accessing-config-var-values-from-code.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman i write smth like this
heroku run echo \$JDBC_DATABASE_URL
also tried this heroku config